# Check progress of database restore running asynchronously

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, powershell

I have a Powershell script that restores a database using the [SqlRestoreAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.sqlrestoreasync.aspx) method.

I have a decent size database which I'm restoring (~55Gb) and I'm trying to find the progress of the restore process.

I know that if I run the restore through a T-SQL command then I can view the progress of the restore by querying a few DMV's or [with the following query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152477/1266737):

```
SELECT r.session_id
    , r.command
    , CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.percent_complete) AS [Percent Complete]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ms, r.estimated_completion_time, GetDate()), 20) AS [ETA Completion Time]
    , CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [Elapsed Min]
    , CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [ETA Min]
    , CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [ETA Hours]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), (
            SELECT SUBSTRING(TEXT, r.statement_start_offset / 2, CASE 
                        WHEN r.statement_end_offset = - 1
                            THEN 1000
                        ELSE (r.statement_end_offset - r.statement_start_offset) / 2
                        END)
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
            )) AS [SQL]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE');
```

This query works fine for T-SQL triggered restores  (or SSMS ones), but doesn't show up the restore progress for the restore triggered by the Powershell script.

I can see my database in SSMS's Object Explorer as being in "Restoring" state, so I know it's working, but .. is it running?

The restore process running this in Async mode seems to take a bit more than when running it through T-SQL, so far twice as much and still not finished.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything obvious about why this command won't be showing up like any other restore command, unless it is busy doing something other than `RESTORE DATABASE`.

I suggest identifying the `session_id` PowerShell is using (you should be able to see in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` or `sys.dm_exec_connections`), or you could change the script to obtain it and print it to the console. Then change your filter to:

```
SELECT command, status, percent_complete, 
  wait_type, last_wait_type, wait_resource,
  blocking_session_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = <x>;
```

This will help you verify:

- if the command is actually a `RESTORE` or if Powershell is actually doing something else first
- current status
- percent complete, **if that is available** ([it isn't always](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql))
- what it's waiting on (and if you run it repeatedly, if this is changing)
- if your restore is actually being blocked by anything

Answer (score 0):

Try listing the active processes:

```
SELECT session_id as SPID
     , command
     , a.text AS Query
     , start_time
     , percent_complete
     , dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a 
--WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

And see if you can spot the process.
(My guess is that the command is an sp_ExecuteSQL)